# Unable to invoke Sagemaker Endpoint

Tags: machine-learning, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, data-preprocessing, automl

I'm using a SageMaker Autopilot deployed model for inference in a Lambda function. The generated model is XGBoost, and I used .parquet files to train it using AutoML in Sagemaker studio.

When I attempt to send a CSV string for prediction, I receive a ModelError with a message saying "could not convert string to float". Here's the sample code I'm using and the error message:

```
import { SageMakerRuntimeClient, InvokeEndpointCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sagemaker-runtime";

const sagemakerRuntime = new SageMakerRuntimeClient({ region: "us-east-2" });

export const handler = async (event) => {
    const testCSV = "False,fff77916386145,0,-1,0,web"
    const params = {
        EndpointName: process.env.ENDPOINT_NAME,
        Body: testCSV,
        ContentType: 'text/csv',
    };

    try {
        const command = new InvokeEndpointCommand(params);
        const response = await sagemakerRuntime.send(command);
        const result = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(response.Body);
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            body: result
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error('Failed to call SageMaker endpoint');
    }
};
```

The error I receive is:

```
ModelError: Received client error (415) from model with message "Loading csv data failed with Exception, please ensure data is in csv format:
 <class 'ValueError'>
 could not convert string to float: 'False'"
```

I've structured the testCSV similar to the training data I used for Sagemaker AutoML, but it seems like the model is not accepting any non-float values. How can I correctly format the data for inference to avoid this error? Is there a place where I can find the correct order of items in CSV for inference?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your get the model working locally( using the local mode or running the docker container) before you move to testing on SageMaker. Often the errors you see are because of serialization and deserialization and in cases where you will need a [custom inference script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/adapt-inference-container.html) and in particular input_fn() function to convert the format that model accepts.